# Working of a phototransistor

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Can anyone explain how photogenerated current in the base gets amplified in a [phototransistor](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=phototransistor). 
If you use band energy diagram, then I would understand more quickly and clearly.

[image]

Comment: Same way as any other base-current amplification in a transistor.  So are you asking how photoelectrons are generated in the base, or how a transistor works?

Comment: Indeed, this question suggests that the workings of a bipolar transistor are not fully grasped.

Comment: As a follow up: assume a silicon npn.  The intrinsic carrier concentration is 1.45E10, so np = 2E20.  If the base is doped to 1E16, than the electron concentration is 2E4.  Electrons from the emitter have no chance of making it to the collector before recombining. Photons make electron-hole pairs.  If the electron concentration is raised to say 1E10, the chance of carriers making it from the emitter to the collector increases tremendously.  The increase in hole concentration is negligible.  Overall, the photo-induced carriers are just like injecting electrons into the base.